# how to use activity beside fragment in fragments click listener

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

i am new to android.
i have fragment "click listener".
this:

```
  package com.raihanbd.easyrambooster;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class MemoryBoosterAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MemoryBoosterAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        Fragment frag = null;
        if (index == 0) {
            frag = new one();
        }

        if (index == 1) {
            frag = new two();
        }

        if (index == 2) {
            frag = new three();
        }

        if (index == 3) {
            frag = new four();
        }

        if (index == 4) {
            frag = new five();
        }
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

}
```

and also i have "activity" that i want to set it beside "fragments".
can anyone help me how to do this?

and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you describe more? That is a ` FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. I don't understand exactly what you want?

Comment: @HoangNguyen thanks for reply, now my problem is this that i can't set "activity" in "frags", i just can set "fragments in "frags".

Comment: `Activity` can't cast to `Fragment`. `Activity` are designed to represent a single screen of the application while `Fragments` are designed to be reusable UI layouts with logic embedded inside of them.  If I am not mistaken, you want created adapter with `activity` is the item?

Answer (score 0):

Is you want to use viewpager? Your code just a adapter,it would be better use a List . 
Here is my code:

```
        public class MemoryBoosterAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private List<Fragment> fragList;

        public MemoryBoosterAdapter(FragmentManager fm,List<Fragment> fragList) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragList = fragList;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {
            return fragList.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragList.size();
        }
}
```

when you use it in MainActivity:

```
private List<Fragment> fragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
fragList.add(new One());  //One is your own fragment
fragList.add(new Two());
// ....

viewpager.setAdapter(new MemoryBoosterAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragList) );
```

Comment: thanks, but my problem is this that i can't set "activity" in "frags", i just can set "fragments in "frags". can you help me?

Comment: You can see.Fragment is a kind of light Activity,and Fragment is based on Activity.If you don't have a activity ,you can't create a fragment either.